# Hacer un update por consola en Mysql a una columna y varios ID's a la vez

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Que tal espero mi pregunta este bien formulada, estoy trabajando con Mysql, en el cual descargo datos en tablas, luego los exporto en excel no tengo ningún problema con eso, el problema se me presento en una columna en la cual descargo datos extra y para corregir eso exporte la tabla y modifique la columna, mi consulta es que deseo actualizar los datos de esa columna son mas de 10000, solo estoy trabajando con base de datos, y quiero hacer eso por consola de mysql.

Con mas detalle:

ejemplo

```
datos de entrada

id       columna2

1         link1

2         link2

3         link3
```

realice cambios en la columna2

ahora será

```
columna2

link7

link8

link9
```

los cambios:mi consulta es que deseo cambiar los valores de la columna 2 pero a través de la consola de mysql(pido disculpas es un ejemplo pero como menciones los datos descargados son mas de 10000), un poco mas claro quiero volver a subir toda la columna en el mismo orden a través de la consola.

```
id       columna2

1         link7

2         link8

3         link9
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], te sugiero en este caso coloques la estructura de la tabla y **una muestra** de los datos de entrada y **una muestra** de los datos de salida que esperas obtener

Comment: Por que no hacer una tabla puente donde insertes los nuevos y después con un UPDATE From JOIN lo actualizas donde coincidan los ID

Comment: Ya pensé en eso créeme, pero seria como volver a crear y bueno se complicara porque tendría que hacer eso varias veces, ya que tengo varias descargas de tablas con el mismo problema, por eso mi consulta si se puede actualizar la columna entera.